# Why printf doesn't show correctly my array?

Tags: c

I have a little problem working with pointers and arrays. The trouble lies on I have a function which creates a new array from the original one, choosing the appropiate characters from a period passed from a parameter. Here is the protype:

```
char *get_string_period(char chain[], uint8_t period);
```

I've used a pointer to that array I want to return because I can't return my new array of characters itself. So I save in main.c this pointer into a variable and I do a printf:

```
char *ptr = get_string_period(chain, period);
printf(“The string of the new array is %s”, ptr);`
```

But printf shows a short version of my generated array. If I print from the function I get:
`vtvfnstrtmwiapjhqsblzgtiapyogiytzhvuswzsfevpsdbljjgmfwoikuvfmoeotwsjwtgussmbegvlxjutktmkzvvvttwlyeqhuwk`
From main.c:
`vtvfnstrtmwiapjhqsblzgti��j`

How can I solve it?
One question more: how can I reuse this array passing it to another function whose parameter is an array itself (char chain[ ])?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The returned pointer points to a local variable array, so it's no longer valid when the function returns.

Comment: Are you properly adding a `NULL` terminator to the end of the string?

Comment: Allow me to take a stab, you're returning a local buffer from `get_string_period()`?

Comment: How is the copy of the array declared in `get_string_period`?

Comment: Please post the code for `get_string_period()` to get more complete answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably `get_string_period` returns a `char` pointer to a local variable, so when the function returned, what it actually returned will point to an invalid address.

Instead of outputting some garbage value, sometimes a segmentation fault occurs in situations like this.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. Thanks for the answer Yu Hao. Sorry for the great mistake.

Comment: @JorgeVicente If you think the answer was useful you can accept that

Comment: A segfault would be better, not worse.  Beter to fail hard and fast then to produce incorrect output (i.e., fail silently).

Answer (score 0):

A char array is terminated by a null byte. That's how printf statement works. It looks for the null byte to end the char array. if your char * doesn't have null byte, printf will keep printing as long as it can.

Comment: A *string* is terminated by a null byte. A `char` array may or may not be. `printf`'s `"%s"` format requires a pointer to (the first character of) a string.